# Python AWS Lambda function invocation succeeds but no elasticsearch index created

Tags: python, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

Caveat: I am an experienced C# developer, but new to Python. I have created a Python AWS Lambda function that I am expecting to post data to my AWS ElasticSearch service to create a new index.

The function succeeds with no errors reported, but there is no activity in my ES domain (I expected a new index to be created). Code and result is below (I'm using the test JSON data from within the AWS console). I probably need some exception handling but am unsure how to get a result back from the ES post?

Assume the following: 
- I have Lambda environment variables for access key, secret key and ES endpoint. I have set up my ES domain with the right access policy for the IAM user in question.

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import boto3
import requests
import json
import os

def send_signed(method, url, service='es', region='ap-southeast-2', body=None):
    credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
    auth = AWS4Auth(os.environ['ACCESS_KEY_ID'], os.environ['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'], 
                  region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

    fn = getattr(requests, method)
    if body and not body.endswith("\n"):
        body += "\n"
    fn(url, auth=auth, data=body, 
       headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Executing function handler")
    print("Event incoming: " + json.dumps(event,indent=2))

    url = os.environ['ES_ENDPOINT']
    doc = json.dumps(event,indent=2)
    send_signed('post', url, body=doc)
```

Result in console:

```
START RequestId: 8e41edee-fda0-11e8-949a-357d7cb2ae6f Version: $LATEST
Executing function handler
Event incoming: {
  "key3": "value3", 
  "key2": "value2", 
  "key1": "value1"
}
END RequestId: 8e41edee-fda0-11e8-949a-357d7cb2ae6f
REPORT RequestId: 8e41edee-fda0-11e8-949a-357d7cb2ae6f  Duration: 386.81 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 36 MB
```

Comment: Did you create an index pattern in Kibana to see your data ?

Comment: My understanding is that I should be able to see the indices within the AWS console (ElasticSearch service screen) without interacting with Kibana. I have tested this by POSTing data via POSTMAN and the index shows up. When the Python function runs however, no index is created.

Comment: I just reverted to using .NET Core for the moment but still keen to understand where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience the best approach is to use [Python's Elasticsearch Client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.13.2/index.html).

With the client, you can [upload documents to your index](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.13.2/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.index) with a single line of code like this:

```
es.index(index=TABLE_NAME, id=doc_id, body=record, request_timeout=100)
```

Check out this [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/bfansports/dynamodb-to-elasticsearch) if you want to learn more about this.